# Download pictures from google images using python

Tags: python, json, image, google-image-search

i have a preety big json file with a lot of car brands and models(more than 1000 cars) and the json file looks like these:

```
{
"0":"honda_civic"
"1":"nissan_leaf"
...
"id":"brand_model"
}
```

and i wander if i can save photos from google and put them into coresponding folders (the path for first element is honda/civic).

My question here is there any function that can get the first result photo from google and save it locally?(it would be great if  it could also sort photos that are
labeled with permission to reuse).

Comment: (It's not me voting down the question, people: be nice) You should try to do some research in google + try to create a python program structure, test it and if doesn't work post it here. This might help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-download-google-images-using-python/

Comment: The problem is that i am not into python programming,  I only know I could do a lot with python and that's why I asked for help in python.

Comment: But how can i filter images  only the images that are labeled  with permission reuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did the trick for me :

```
import json
myjson=json.load(open('id.json','rb'))
print("starting")
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import urllib.request
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
i=0
def searchnsave(id,key_word):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe") #incase you are chrome
    browser.get("https://www.google.com/search?q="+key_word+"&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi2hvndl-jqAhWSkqQKHffTA5sQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq="+key_word+"&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIECAAQE1D2FVj2FWDHG2gAcAB4AIABUogBUpIBATGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=LAgcX7bAM5KlkgX3p4_YCQ&bih=722&biw=1519&tbs=sur%3Afc&hl=ro")
    #search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
    #search.send_keys(key_words,Keys.ENTER)
    #elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Images')
    #elem.get_attribute('href')
    #elem.click()
    value = 0
    #for i in range(20):
     #  browser.execute_script("scrollBy("+ str(value) +",+1000);")
     #  value += 1000
     #  time.sleep(3)
    elem1 = browser.find_element_by_id('islmp')
    sub = elem1.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")
    count = 0
    for i in sub:
            src = i.get_attribute('src')
            try:
                if src != None:
                    src  = str(src)
                    print(src)
                    count+=1
                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, os.path.join('downloads',key_word+'.jpg'))
                else:
                    raise TypeError
            except TypeError:
                print('fail')
            break
    browser.close()


for k,v in myjson.items():
    print(k,v)
    searchnsave(k,v)
```

But dont forget to first install selenium with the following command:

```
pip3 install selenium
```

and also install correct chromedriver.exe from here : http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html